# UIScrollView stops (or slows down) scrolling between stops defined by Paging

Tags: ios, performance, uiscrollview, unity-game-engine, slowdown

I have an iOS App that uses Unity3D. When I pause Unity to show only Quartz-related content, the performance is usually fine.

But on a current project, **scrollviews and table views sometimes perform very bad**. They stop scrolling too early, and the scrollview stops even between multiples of the size predefined by the paging.

I tried to take a look with Instruments, and found FPS is usually ~50-60, but sometimes less. However this does not answer my question.

Btw, the table and the scroller have only a few data, and there is no reloading issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now I found some very helpful information at the [Unity Forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/113815-quot-Sticky-quot-scrolling-in-UITableView-and-UIScrollView-when-interfacing-Unity-and-Obj-C). Using

```
#define USE_DISPLAY_LINK_IF_AVAILABLE 0
```

prevents the described issue. The Unity-iOS project now uses THREAD_BASED_LOOP instead of the CADisplayLink class. Maybe I will further play around with CADisplayLink and lower target frame rates.

Some interesting information about the used Rendering Loop Type can be found in the [Unity Manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/352/Documentation/Manual/iphone-Optimizing-MainLoop.html).